# Argument type 'bool' is not assignment to parameter type 'int'

Tags: c#

I initialized bool variable like this

```
 bool isActionAt= true;
```

But when i try to access i got the different error.

> Argument type 'bool' is not assignment to parameter type 'int'

When i give `bool isActionAt= "1";`

then i got this error

> Cannot convert source type string to target type bool

Comment: Can you post little more of the code.

Comment: You are not in c++ anymore, Dorothy :-)

Answer (score 4):

Well you haven't shown how you're trying to use it as an `int`, but this is clearly wrong:

```
bool isActionAt = "1";
```

A `bool` variable can only have a value of `true` or `false`. "1" isn't one of those values, and there's no *implicit conversion* from a string to a `bool`.

You may be used to very dynamically-typed languages, which convert data of different types for you implicitly: C# tends to shy away from that. When there's a conversion available which doesn't lose information, there's often an implicit conversion, e.g.

```
short x = 10;
int y = x;
```

(Some floating point conversions *can* lose information, but...)

If information might be lost, you typically have to use an explicit conversion:

```
int x = 100;
short y = (short) x; // short has a smaller range than int
```

For `string` and `bool` however, there isn't *any* conversion available within the language, so you'd have to write your own, specifying which string values should be deemed true and which should be deemed false.

If you could try to explain what you're trying to *achieve* rather than the code yo're using to try to achieve it, we may be able to help you. At the moment all we know is that your code is invalid.

Comment: seems OP migrated from the planet of C, "1"[0] ;)

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad: So what are you *trying to do*? You mustn't treat C# as if it were C - they have very different idioms, even aside from what's simply valid.

Comment: @Anonymous: Which would also be incorrect in the case of the false value ie `"0"[0]`.

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad: Well that gives us a *clue* as to what you're trying to do, but it doesn't explain where strings get involved, or the bigger picture. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet:- what would you recommend about `bool isActionAt= "1"=="1";`

Comment: @Anonymous that would always be true... so why wouldn't you just say `bool isActionAt = true;` ? However, what *would* make sense is: `bool isActionAt = someValue == "1";`

Comment: @MarcGravell:- Just wanted to know, if such comparisions have some side effects. :)

Comment: @leppie:- No, in C/C++ its still true; 0 is ascii 48 and has 1 in its bit representation :P ;)

Comment: @Anonymous: That was leppie's point, I believe. The OP would probably *expect "0" to give false, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want do is assign to a boolean the value of an int variable, what you could do is a conditional, stating that if the variable has a value of '1' then make the bool 'true', or false otherwise.

You could also try casting the integer to a boolean. I seem to recall that too would work similarly to what you were trying to do.